# True random number generation using cell phone

Tags: random

Consider a scenario.

True random number generation procedure demands that you have an external hardware device or external system attached to your system from which you can generate true random numbers.A usefulness of true random numbers is that they are hard to reproduce and are widely used in cryptographic applications.

**My Method of True Random Number Generation**

I have a following scenario.I have radio in my cell phone by tuning my radio to specific known frequency i will output cell phone sound(voice) data to my desktop c# or java application and read raw bytes which i guess will be random.(?)

Is my procedure correct?
if not what can be done in my scenario?

Comment: Will your radio always be available?

Comment: only when i need to generate TRN(True Random Numbers)

Comment: How about repeatedly initializing your random number generator with seed based on delay between user pressing keys (in milliseconds). Or changes in gyroscope position. You can do this offline.

Comment: That also sounds promising but from where to start i mean is there article on it that i can read and implement it.